# Is there a tool out there that extracts the main text in an email?

Tags: nlp, text-processing, machine-learning

What I'm looking for is a tool that detects salutations/greetings, signature, quotation of another email, legal notices and separates all of this "noise" from the main content of the email.

For example, given an email:

> Hi John,
>
> Please send me the report on insect repellents you have prepared last
>   week.
>
> Thanks, Bob

It would extract "Please send me the report on insect repellents you have prepared last week.".

Of course it would get more complex if the email is long and contains a lot of quoted text from the previous emails in the same thread.

I imagine there must be a tool similar to BoilerPipe, but for emails instead of webpages.

Any ideas?

Comment: Regular Expressions and a lot of Time ! ;)
No Seriously, that Programm would need to know all kinds of greetings to work. I am not aware of such a tool, but you could try to write your own tool.